# Parsing rss feed using retrofit and simplexmlconverter

Tags: android, xml-parsing, retrofit, rss-reader, simple-xml-converter

I am trying since last two day for parsing the rss feed of my website using `Retrofit` and `retrofit2.converter.simplexml`. It's parsing the basic tag but not like `content:encoded` etc.
I am posting the rss xml [LINK OF RSS](https://mirzapurofficial.in/category/viral-news/feed/) and retrofit's code here.
The problem is this is not parsing content:encoded and category.
Retrofit

```
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(EndPoints.BASE_URL)
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
```

POJO classes

```
@Root(name = "rss", strict = false)
class RssFeed {
    @Element
    var channel: RssChannel? = null
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "RssFeed [channel=$channel]"
    }
}

@Root(name = "channel", strict = false)
class RssChannel {
    @Element
    private val title: String? = null

    @Element
    private val image: RssImage? = null

    @ElementList(inline = true, required = false)
    var item: List<RssItem>? = null
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Channel [image=$image, item=$item]"
    }
}

@Root(name = "item", strict = false)
class RssItem {

    @Element
    var title: String? = null

    @Element
    var link: String? = null

    @Element
    var pubDate: String? = null

    @Element
    var description: String? = null

    var imageUrl: String? = null

    @Element
    var category: String? = null

    @Element(name = "content", required = true, type = String::class)
    var content: String? = null


    override fun toString(): String {
        return ("RssItem [title=" + title + ", link=" + link + ", pubDate=" + pubDate
                + ", description=" + description + "content=" + content + "]")
    }
}

@Root(name = "image", strict = false)
class RssImage {
    @Element
    private val url: String? = null

    @Element
    private val width: String? = null

    @Element
    private val height: String? = null
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "RssImage [url=$url, width=$width, height=$height]"
    }
}
```

Category error is

```
onFailure(java.lang.RuntimeException: org.simpleframework.xml.core.PersistenceException: Element 'category' is already used with @org.simpleframework.xml.Element(data=false, name=, required=true, type=void)
```